# 2 iPhones, 1 computer. Why are they now both running on the same iTunes account?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have recently synced my partner's iPhone to my computer because his computer crashed. He has his own iTunes account so we backed his phone up to iCloud, wiped it a re-synced it to my computer.
But when he tried to access iTunes through his iPhone (to download music or new apps) it takes him to my account and asks for my password.
In settings on his iPhone under iTunes account it still has his user ID. How do we get access to his iTunes account from his iPhone back?

Answer (score 1):

Why not log out your iTunes account so that he can log in his iTunes account?

Comment: And how should they to that (as it seems this is exactly what they are trying to do here)?